# Lockless synchronized access to ConditionalWeakTable

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, lock-free

I am inexperienced with writing multithreaded applications, and I am trying to wrap a [ConditionalWeakTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.conditionalweaktable-2?view=net-8.0) (`CWT`) for use as a generalized container type. I'm aware that `CWT` is thread-safe, but I want to synchronize access to the table with other operations in the collection without locking. This is my attempt so far:

```
public sealed class CwtWrapper<TKey, TValue>
    where TKey : class
    where TValue : class?, new()
{
    private readonly CwtHolder _cwtHolder = new();
    
    private sealed class CwtHolder
    {
        private ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue>? _cwt = [];
        
        public CwtProvider GetCwtProvider() => new(this);
    
        public sealed class CwtProvider : IDisposable, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
        {
            private readonly CwtHolder _cwtHolder;
            private readonly ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue> _cwt;
            
            public CwtProvider(CwtHolder cwtHolder)
            {
                _cwtHolder = cwtHolder;
                ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue>? cwt = null;
                SpinWait.SpinUntil(() =>
                {
                    cwt = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _cwtHolder._cwt, null);
                    return cwt is not null;
                });
                _cwt = cwt!;
            }
            
            public void Add(TKey key, TValue value) => _cwt.Add(key, value);
            public void AddOrUpdate(TKey, TValue value) => _cwt.AddOrUpdate(key, value);
            public void Clear() => _cwt.Clear();
            public void Dispose() => _cwtHolder._cwt = _cwt;
            public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_cwt).GetEnumerator();
            IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
            public TValue GetOrCreateValue(TKey key) => _cwt.GetOrCreateValue(key);
            public TValue GetValue(TKey key, ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue>.CreateValueCallback createValueCallback) => _cwt.GetValue(key, createValueCallback);
            public bool Remove(TKey key) => _cwt.Remove(key);
            public bool TryAdd(TKey key, TValue value) => _cwt.TryAdd(key, value);
            public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue? value) => _cwt.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        }
    }
}
```

The `CWT` object is held inside of the `CwtHolder` object, which does not directly expose the `CWT`. Access to the `CWT` is provided through the [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-8.0) wrapper `CwtProvider`.

`CwtProvider` *steals* the `CWT` object away from the `CwtHolder` (using [Interlocked.Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.exchange?view=net-8.0)) in its constructor, and *restores* the `CWT` when disposed. If the `CwtHolder` did not have the `CWT`, then a [SpinWait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.spinwait?view=net-8.0) is used until the previous `CwtProvider` is disposed.

This would then be used to synchronize other operations in the `CwtWrapper` collection:

```
// inside CwtWrapper
public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
{
    using var cwt = _cwtHolder.GetCwtProvider();
    // do some work with the CWT; other threads won't have access to it
    cwt.Add(key, value);
    // cwt.Dispose is called, restoring other threads' access to the CWT
}
```

**Questions:**

- Is this a valid lockless synchronization approach?
- What are the potential problems with this approach?
- If `CwtProvider` is exclusively used inside of `using` statements, is there a potential that it will not be disposed (e.g., maybe if the thread is aborted)?
- Is there a *better* way to synchronize access to the `CWT` with other operations in the `CwtWrapper` **without** using locks?

**Edit:** I overlooked [SpinWait.SpinUntil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.spinwait.spinuntil?view=net-8.0) because it is a static method.